# Jenkins: How to Integrate source management plugin(perforce) with ldap

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, perforce

I am new to Jenkins and trying to setup perforce(source management) plugin.

The perforce in our organization is integrated with company's ldap.

I have successfully integrated Jenkins login with company's ldap. However, after installing perforce plugin, I don't see an option to use existing logged in user's credential for perforce login or even integrate ldap login for perforce.

When I try to setup credentials,it simply asks for perforce login & password which would mean storing only 1 user's credentials.

[image]

Basically I am going to create a build job which could be triggered by more than 1 people so I want the user/admin who has logged in to Jenkins to provide his credntials for perforce.

[image]

How can I use ldap to login to perforce in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user credentials used for checking out sources from perforce are distinct from those used for logging in to Jenkins. They have nothing to do with each other.

By enabling project based security for a Jenkins job you can configure which users (that is users logged in to Jenkins, which could be authenticated via LDAP) are allowed to trigger a job.
Once the job is triggered it will check out sources as the perforce user that you configured in the job configuration.
IMHO it is wise to a have a dedicated Jenkins/build user in perforce, so that all jobs in Perforce use that p4-user for building any job.

Note:
use the Credentials plugin to centrally configure and store LDAP- and P4-credentials.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I didn't understand your statement: "The user credentials used for checking out sources from perforce are distinct from those used for logging in to Jenkins. They have nothing to do with each other". In my case both are same i.e. the user is picked from ldap in both the cases.

Comment: In your case a P4 user is authenticated via LDAP, but that still doesn't mean that a user logged in to Jenkins is the same user that Jenkins uses in order to checkout sources. These users got to be different. What if two Jenkins users manually trigger the same job? Then the job should still use the same P4 user.

Comment: Ok. I understand your point that why 2 are different. But why should same P4 user be used in the job?

Comment: Imagine you have 100 Jenkins jobs. It wouldn't be good to configure all jobs to use different p4 users. Unless you have some p4 permission policies that restrict read access for some depot parts, it's good practise that all those jobs use one single p4 account.

Comment: Is there a way not to hardcode this P4 user and instead give it at the time of running the job?

Comment: Hm. What you could do is configure a set of relevant p4 credentials (using the credentials plugin). That way the user/password is safely stored and can be referenced by an credentials-id. Then instead of configuring the job via the WebUI you can configure it via a pipeline script (which is more work if you are just starting but less work if you have to maintain many jobs, many products, many branches, etc.). In the pipeline script you have the freedom to choose the p4 credentials.

Comment: Mind, that if you use an existing p4 workspace/client with a different user you run into an error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169149/discussion-between-pitseeker-and-catchingup).